# Rule in firewall for vmware

Tags: vmware

Should there be some sort of rule in the firewall that lets your vmware host server get out to the internet?

I have changed IP addressees, dns entries and still having an issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are having problem in connecting your host VM to the internet. Yes, there are firewall rules that control the rights of VmWare(as like all softwares and services).

Try changing the **Network Settings** under **Attached to**. In most cases, NAT Network and Bridged Adapter works, but depending on your requirement and network layout/permissions you can switch among them and it should work fine.